# Git hook pre-commit error: "command not found"

Tags: git, github, vbscript, githooks

I have a simple Git hook that calls some other (VBScript) scripts. The script runs correctly when I call it from the command line. However, when the hook is executed, it gives me the following error(s):

```
./RevisionDate.vbs: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./RevisionDate.vbs: line 1: `Set copyFSO = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")'
.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 8: Start-Sleep: command not found
test
./MovePDF.vbs: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./MovePDF.vbs: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Here is the VBScript that gets called in the hook.

```
Set copyFSO = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
copyFSO.copyFile "C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\Test\*.pdf", "C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\Test2"
copyFSO.moveFile "C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\Test\*.pdf", "C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\Temp"

'------ Microsoft Excel -------

inputPrefix = cint(inputbox("Please enter two digit prefix for file you would like updated.", "File Update"))
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False
sFolder = "C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\Test"
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files
    fileName = oFile
    Set objWorkbook = nothing
    Set objSelection = nothing
    Set objWorksheet = nothing

    If UCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "XLSX" Then
        Prefix = left(oFile.Name, 2)
        filePrefix = cint(Prefix)
        Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
        Set objSelection = objExcel.Selection
        Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
        myYear = Year(Now())
        myMonth = Month(Now())
        myDay = Day(Now())
        myDate = myYear & "/" & myMonth & "/" & myDay
        myDateFile = myYear & "-" & myMonth & "-" & myDay

        If (filePrefix = inputPrefix) then
            objWorksheet.PageSetup.RightFooter = "Revision Date: " & myDate & " C"
            objWorkbook.Save
        End If

        fileName = Replace(oFile.Name, ".xlsx", "")
        saveAndCloseXlsx objWorkbook
    End if
Next

Function saveAndCloseXlsx(objWorkbook)
    objWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat xiTypePDF, "C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\Test\" & fileName
    objWorkbook.Close
end Function


'------ Microsoft Word -------

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False
sFolder = "C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\Test"
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files

    If UCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "DOCX" Then
        fileName = oFile
        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(fileName)
        Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

        If objDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("RevisionDate") = True Then
            Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("RevisionDate").Range
            myYear = Year(Now())
            myMonth = Month(Now())
            myDay = Day(Now())
            myDate = myYear & "/" & myMonth & "/" & myDay
            myDateFile = myYear & "-" & myMonth & "-" & myDay
            Prefix = left(oFile.Name, 2)
            filePrefix = cint(Prefix)

            If (inputPrefix = filePrefix) then
                objRange.text = "Revision Date: " & myDate & " C"
                objDoc.Bookmarks.Add "RevisionDate", objRange
            End If

            wdFormatPDF = 17
            SaveAndCloseDocx objDoc
        End If
    End if
Next

set oFSO = Nothing
objWord.Quit

Function SaveAndCloseDocx(objDoc)
    fileName = Replace(oFile.Name, ".docx", "")
    objDoc.SaveAs "C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\Test\" & fileName & ".pdf", wdFormatPDF
    objDoc.Close
End Function
```

And finally the hook itself:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#
echo "Script Running"
cd 'C:\Users\Ian\desktop\QMS_Manual'
"./RevisionDate.vbs"
Start-Sleep -s 30
"./MovePDF.vbs"
cd 'C:\Users\Ian\desktop\Test2'
pdftk *.pdf cat output ECMWC.pdf
cd 'C:\Users\Ian\desktop\QMS_Manual'
DeleteAllButFinal.vbs
```

Why does this happen? I've read it may have something to do with the [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environment variable.

Comment: @Kev On the Powershell aspect: I previously had a wrapper script that was in Powershell but have since removed it. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Given that this is BASH, wouldn't you need to escape all of those backslashes?

Comment: @whoisj Do you mean change the backslashes to common slashes?

Comment: Are you using msysgit or Git for Windows?

Comment: @kev i am using github

Comment: Sure, but how or what git bits did you install locally and where from?

Comment: @Kev Git for Windows I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to prefix the calls to your `.vbs` scripts with:

```
cscript yourscript.vbs
```

You're running a Bash/sh script from your Git hook.

Your Bash/sh implementation won't know what to do with `Start-Sleep` because that's a PowerShell command. You'll need to find some Bash equivalent or shell out to PowerShell to execute that statement.

The script then tries to execute the contents of `RevisionDate.vbs` and `MovePDF.vbs` as Bash/sh statements rather than launch the VBScript interpreter that would normally be associated under a `cmd.exe` command shell. So you need to tell your shell script how to do this, i.e., `cscript yourscript.vbs`.

**Paths:**

Also watch those paths. Most Windows Bash/sh shell implementations won't know what `C:\blah\blah` means (the `\` is used as an escape character). Instead you need to use Unix-style paths. For example,

```
'C:\Users\Ian\desktop\Test2'
```

would translate to:

```
/c/Users/Ian/desktop/Test2
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it did not resolve or change the error message

Comment: Okay so theoretically I would have to go through the whole VBScript and convert to bash for it to run? Is there any way to run a VBScript normally?

Comment: @IanPennebaker Ok, open a gitbash console then type `cscript`, hit return, and tell me what you see.

Comment: `Options:
 //B         Batch mode: Suppresses script errors and prompts from displaying
 //D         Enable Active Debugging
 //E:engine  Use engine for executing script
 //H:CScript Changes the default script host to CScript.exe
 //H:WScript Changes the default script host to WScript.exe (default)
 //I         Interactive mode (default, opposite of //B)
 //Job:xxxx  Execute a WSF job
 //Logo      Display logo (default)
 //Nologo    Prevent logo display: No banner will be shown at execution time
 //S         Save current command line options for this user
`

Comment: `//T:nn      Time out in seconds:  Maximum time a script is permitted to run
 //X         Execute script in debugger
 //U         Use Unicode for redirected I/O from the console` @Kev

Comment: Sorry, that is difficult to read. I appreciate your help. @Kev

Comment: @IanPennebaker Right, what I'm saying is that you need to call the cscript interpreter from your bash script so *cscript* interprets and executes your `.vbs` scripts. Git's bash won't know how to do that just by specifying the name of a random script containing statements it won't understand.

Comment: Thank you very much. You just saved me a lot of headache!

Comment: @IanPennebaker you're welcome chap. :)  Have also added a bit about paths in these types of bash/sh ports to Windows.